# Как конвертировать .cer в .bks keystore?

Tags: android

Мне нужно конвертировать .cer to BKS certificate

Вот как описано в этом ответе на SO

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284466/how-to-convert-cer-to-bks

Я сделал так, у меня есть папка в которую я сложил

- keytool.exe
- bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar
- Root_CA.cer

Открываю Windows PowerShell и пишу (заменяя данные на свои)

.\keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "path_to_cert/interm_ca.cer" -alias IntermediateCA -keystore "path_to_your_app/res/raw/myKeystore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "path_to_bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16-145.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mysecret

нажимаю Enter и ничего не происходит

ни сообщения об ошибке, ничего

Что делаю не так? Как все таки конвертировать этот файл?

**Правка**

Если я набираю эту команду без `.\` знака

вот так `keytool -importcert -v -trustcac.........` то получаю такую ошибку

> keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1 + keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "C:\Users\alexey.t\Downloa ... + ~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> Suggestion [3,General]: The command keytool was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\keytool". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

**ПРАВКА**

получилось так, запустил `cmd` пошел в папку где сидит `keystore.exe` и написал команду как указал в вопросе только без `.\`

keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "C:\Users\alexey.t\Downloads\my_certificates\Root_CA.cer" -alias IntermediateCA -keystore "C:\Users\alexey.t\Downloads\my_certificates" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "C:\Users\alexey.t\Downloads\my_certificates\bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mysecret

и получил вот такое сообщение

> Certificate already exists in system-wide CA keystore under alias 
>   Do you still want to add it to your own keystore? [no]:  yes
>
> Certificate was added to keystore
>   [Storing \Users\alexey.t\Downloads\my_certificates]
>
> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\alexey.t\Downloads\my_certificates (The system cannot find the path specified)
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\alexey.t\Downloads\my_certificates (The system cannot find the path specified)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Unknown Source)

В итоге в дирректории `C:\Users\alexey.t\Downloads\my_certificates` файла с расширением `.bks` который я ожидаю увидеть там нет.

И вот есть такая команда для проверки что `keystore` содержиться

keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\alexey.t\Downloads\MyApp\app\src\res\raw\myKeystore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "C:\Users\alexey.t\Downloads\my_certificates\bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mysecret

Вот что получаю

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\alexey.t\Downloads\MyApp\app\src\res\raw\myKeystore.bks

Что теперь не так?

Comment: Абажди. Ты открываешь павершелл, но стоит тег баш. Или ты запускаешь павершелл в линуксе?

Comment: @donRumata нет, я на винде работаю. Только не понял, что ты имел ввиду? что не так?

Comment: Shell в названии PowerShell не имеет ничего общего с POSIX shell.

Comment: Тогда при чём тут тег bash?

Comment: @donRumata понял что ты имел ввиду. Исправил

Comment: Удалил тег "баш". Ну ок. Следующий вопрос. Зачем запускать внутри пошика? Чем cmd не устраивает?

Comment: @donRumata что то получилось, но теперь другая проблема. Добавил в вопрос правку

Comment: Куча ошибок `java-чё-то там` у тебя jre или чё-то типа того установлен? Очень похоже, что в системе каких-то бибилиотек не хватает.

Comment: @donRumata если я правильно понял то ты спросил от куда я использую `keytool` , то я использую его из `jre` вот такой путь `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\keytool.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге получилось получить `.bks` файл

Пошагово, что сделал

1. Открыл `cmd`
2. Пошел в дирректорию где сидит `keytool.exe` (в моем случае `../ProgramFiles/Java/jre_1.8.0/bin`)
3. Положил файл сертификата и файл `BouncyCastle` в другую дирректорию (в моем случае `C:\LocalGit\certificate`)
4. Написал такую команду

   keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file

   "C:\LocalGit\certificate\Root_CA.cer" -alias IntermediateCA -

   keystore "C:\LocalGit\certificate\keystore.bks" -provider

   org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath

   "C:\LocalGit\certificate\bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mysecret

Потом там выпал вопрос о том, что такой файл содержиться и хочу ли я его перезаписать я ввел `yes` и получил файл с расширением `.bks` в дирректории 
`C:\LocalGit\certificate`